# How to get Ionic icons (ionicons) to work at Android stock browser?

Tags: fonts, ionic-framework, android-browser, font-family, ionicons

I'm using Ionic Framework.

I'm using following piece of code:

```
<div class="list list-inset">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="data.searchText.name">
  </label>
</div>
```

It is taken directly from the official docs: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#input-icons.

It works relatively well across the board, but fails with the stock Android browser (tested on physical HTC One X 4.0.4 and Genymotion Galaxy Nexus 4.3).

### I tried using Weinre to inspect the element

[image]

### I tried modifying CSS:

```
.ion-search:before {
  font-family:"Times New Roman" !important;
  color: black;
  content: "wider wider \f21f"; 
}
```

[image]

### I checked if :pseudo classes are supported

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

### I created simple demo to see they are actually supported (they are)

http://plnkr.co/edit/o5BK6KqTk1MNrlMOI7o5?p=preview

---

And this stage I feel entitle to ask... What is required to get the icons to work?

*(many thanks for that)*

UPDATE: http://bit.ly/aaaabbbccc icons works in the stock browser, I'm still trying to figure out why they don't in my code...

UPDATE: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/19816/59510 - handy link instructing how to delete browser cache / local storage / any other settings

UPDATE: http://1drv.ms/1fWdHpi - I recorded a video... It is intermittent with so many possible states.

Comment: Hey there, seems like an odd issue. Do the icons appear when you install your cordova/phonegap app on your phone?

Comment: It's a mobile web app in the first instance. When I do cordova/phonegap wrapper I'll update the thread and tell how it goes.

Comment: Keep in mind ionic stance on where it fits in. http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/#browser-support